# Custom environment with options for tikz

Tags: environments, expl3

I wanted to create a custom environment and I am currently facing the following problem:

- I want to pass an Option to my environment which scales the tikzpicture but the first example does not work and returns the following error -> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
- The second one seems to work but I do not understand why the first one does not if it is similar to the second one.
- The error is caused by the following code:
  -> `scale = \scalevalue`

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn{test} {
    scale .tl_set:N = \l_test_scale_tl,
    scale .default:n = 1,
    scale .initial:n  = 1
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{o}
    {
        % Options
        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \IfNoValueF{#1}{\keys_set:nn {test}{#1}}
        \ExplSyntaxOff
        
        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \newcommand*{\scalevalue}{\the\numexpr\l_test_scale_tl\relax}
        
        \ExplSyntaxOff
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = \scalevalue, transform shape]
    }
    {
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}
% Example 1: Error
%\begin{myenv}
%\node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
%\end{myenv}

% Example 2: No error
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand*{\scalevalue}{\l_test_scale_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = \scalevalue, transform shape]
\node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `\ExplSyntaxOn` too late. It has to be activated at the moment when `\NewDocumentEnvironment` is read, because at this moment it is decided how e.g. `_` will be processed. So you need something like

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{o}{... no switching of \ExpSyntax ...}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

But now also `tikzpicture`, in particular the space between `transform` and `shape` is in the scope of this syntax, and tikz will complain that `transformshape` (without space) is not known.

You can do something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn{test} {
    scale .tl_set:N = \l_test_scale_tl,
    scale .default:n = 1,
    scale .initial:n  = 1
  }
\newcommand\preparePic[1]{%
  \IfNoValueF{#1}{\keys_set:nn {test}{#1}}%
  \newcommand*{\scalevalue}{\the\numexpr\l_test_scale_tl\relax}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{o}
    {
        \preparePic{#1}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = \scalevalue, transform shape]
    }
    {
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
\node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```